# How to derive Euler-Maclaurin sum formula using Taylor series?

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics, derivatives, summation

[image]

Hi readers, **After sub in B1 that is -1/2,** shouldn't the result be **-f(n)+f(0)** instead of **f(n)+f(0)**.
By the way, the highlighted part is correct but I would like some clarification on how to arrive at this highlighted part.

**Please refer to**  https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath643/kmath643.htm

Comment: Yes, I think that's a typo. It should be $f(0)-f(n)$.

Comment: @K.defaoite Hi, The highlighted part is the correct Euler-Maclaurin Summation formula!! It is not wrong!!

Comment: I think there are different conventions, depending on where you start the summation. See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula)

Comment: @K.defaoite Can you give an example?

Comment: What do you mean by example? It's just a question of adding/subtracting $f(0)$ from either side.

Comment: @K.defaoite If you change  f(n)+f(0) to -f(n)+f(0), then it is not Euler-Maclaurin formula anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} f(k) = f(n) + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(k) = f(n) + S^{(0)}. $$

So the highlighted part is the consequence of the computation

$$ f(n) + \frac{B_1}{1!}[f(n) - f(0)] = \frac{1}{2}[f(n) + f(0)]. $$

Comment: Thank you!! Too dumb to see that haha :(